# Dynamically added menu (PXAction + MenuAutoOpen + AddMenuAction) gets hidden in some screens, but not others

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to dynamically add a menu and related actions through a graph extension. The code I have written works in some screens but not in others. I can see the menu appear during post-back but it gets hidden right away: http://recordit.co/T5KSEz7QJv

I have spent a few hours investigating the problem and here's what I found so far:

- If I don't add my action to a menu, it works in every cases. The issue is only when using AddMenuAction. I see that there's some logic inside PXAction to show/hide the menu based on visibility of the items inside the menu, but I couldn't figure the problem out.
- If the menu itself is directly declared in the graph extension (using public PXAction... and attributes), it works as expected. It is *not* an option in my case because I am trying to create a generic mechanism that will allow me to add actions to any graph type.

The two following graph extensions highlight this problem - the first one is for Sales Orders entry, and the other for Business Account maintenance. They are identical, except for the graph type parameter:

```
//This extension works fine, button displays as expected
public class TestButtonsSO : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();

        Type primaryViewItemType = Base.Views[Base.PrimaryView].Cache.GetItemType();

        var myMenu = PXNamedAction.AddAction(Base, primaryViewItemType, "MyMenu", "My Menu",
                    a => a.Get(),
                    new PXEventSubscriberAttribute[] { new PXButtonAttribute() { MenuAutoOpen = true } });

        var action = PXNamedAction.AddAction(Base, primaryViewItemType, "MyMenu$Test", "Test",
            a => throw new PXException("Clicked!"),
            new PXEventSubscriberAttribute[] { new PXButtonAttribute() { } });

        myMenu.AddMenuAction(action);
    }
}

//The menu will appear during post-back but gets hidden right away
public class TestButtonsBAccount: PXGraphExtension<BusinessAccountMaint>
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();

        Type primaryViewItemType = Base.Views[Base.PrimaryView].Cache.GetItemType();

        var myMenu = PXNamedAction.AddAction(Base, primaryViewItemType, "MyMenu", "My Menu", 
                    a => a.Get(),
                    new PXEventSubscriberAttribute[] { new PXButtonAttribute() { MenuAutoOpen = true } });

        var action = PXNamedAction.AddAction(Base, primaryViewItemType, "MyMenu$Test", "Test", 
            a => throw new PXException("Clicked!"),
            new PXEventSubscriberAttribute[] { new PXButtonAttribute() { } });

        myMenu.AddMenuAction(action);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon the investigation, this issue seems to be caused by PXGridWithPreview corrupting ToolBarItemCollection in the DataSource. Your approach above will perfectly work on all Acumatica screens, which do not contain a PXGridWithPreview control. For screens already utilizing PXGridWithPreview, we'll have to wait until a fix is realised by Acumatica Engineering Team (will keep this item on my radar and post an update once the fix is available)

Comment: Thanks a lot for investigating the issue

Comment: @RuslanDev has this issue been resolved or roadmapped? Or has a workaround been found?